# Query question: Is there a better way to select all records from one table, along with unmatched records from another table?

Tags: sql, select, join

Consider the following:

```
**Customers**
CustomerId (PK)
LastName
FirstName
Address1
City
State
Zip

**CustomerMailingAddresses**
CustomerId (PK)/(FK)
Address1
City
State
Zip
```

Basically, there's a one-to-one relationship between the two tables.  However, not every customer record in Customers has an entry in the CustomerMailingAddresses table.  I'm attempting to use T-SQL (Sql Server 2008) to generate a list of customer names and addreses.  However, I only want to return the address from CustomerMailingAddresses as well as all addresses from Customers that do not have a corresponding entry for each CustomerId in CustomerMailingAddresses.  In other words, the entry in CustomerMailingAddresses (if there is one), will act as an override for the address in Customers.

I've hit a wall, as none of the queries I've tried will work.  I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: What queries have you tried that haven't worked?

Comment: Select *
From Customers left join CustomerMailingAddresses 
On Customers.CustomerId = CustomerMailingAddresses.CustomerId
where CustomerMailingAddresses.Address IS NULL      --Above one had a spelling mistake.

Comment: I initially started off using a LEFT JOIN with the CustomerMailingAddresses table as the left table. Here's the furthest I got: SELECT Address, City State, Zip FROM CustomerMailingAddresses cma LEFT JOIN Customers c ON cma.Customerid=c.CustomerId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [COALESCE](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-coalesce.html)

```
select
    c.CustomerId,
    COALESCE(m.Address1, c.Address1) as Address1,
    COALESCE(m.City, c.City) as City,
    COALESCE(m.State, c.State) as State,
    COALESCE(m.Zip, c.Zip) as Zip
from Customers c
left join CustomerMailingAddresses m on m.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```

Comment: There must not be any columns in CustomerMailingAddresses that are marked as nullable.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
MINUS
SELECT Customers.*
       FROM Customers, CustomerMailingAddresses
       WHERE Customers.CustomerId = CustomerMailingAddresses.CustomerId
```

(sorry if my SQL is a bit rusty)